# Google Cloud Functions : Why won't this work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm starting with Google Cloud Functions, using NodeJs 8. (I'm also new to NodeJS as well, but not with javascript)
I'm a bit lost while browsing the documentation, the samples on github, "old" article on the subject, and I'm frustrated not being able to make some decent progress.

**My Question is : If you can explain me why some syntax don't work :)**

Here are some of the things that currently puzzle me:

- the sample I find on github or Google Cloud documentation, just don't work OOTB

This syntax won't work with Google Cloud Functions : you have to remove the curly braces so that it works.

taken from this doc : https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/0.22.x/Publisher

```
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
```

- NodeJS8 is supposed to support **async** keyword which is used in samples I've found on Github, and I get a Syntax Error when I save my function, while Node8 is selected.

Example of samples : https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/samples/tables.js

- I can spot two type of syntax, one with callbacks, one with promise chaining.

Within the same documentation I read callback technic :

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/0.22.x/Publisher

```
publisher.publish(data, attributes, callback);
```

I've also seen some other syntax with "promise chaining" technic:

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/0.22.x/

```
publisher.publish(data).then().catch()
```

Are both method working ? I don't get why there's support for callback with the "promise chaining" being available ? Which one is the best to use? (backward compatibility?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the issue comes from "outdated" or "wrong" documentation, I believe the issue is comming from elsewhere.

**1. [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment) (curly braces in variables) throws a Syntax Error**

I just tried your example myself in a Node.js 8 Cloud Function and it's working. Added the PubSub library to the Cloud Function package.json, added the line you shared to the code, and it worked.

You could add the error message your receive or try creating a new Cloud Function altogether, because the syntax you shared is definitely possible to use in Cloud Functions. Also, try a simpler destructuring code and check if it works, for example:

```
exports.destructuringTest = (data, context) => {
  const complexObject = {simpleObject: "Hello"};
  const {simpleObject} = complexObject;

  console.log(simpleObject); // You should see "Hello" in the CF logs
};
```

**2. Using the [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) keyword throws a Syntax Error**

It's weird, the same as in the first question happens, I can use the `async` works on my end. I suggest the same as previously, share the complete error message, create a new Cloud Function and try with a simpler example. My Cloud Function worked with this:

```
exports.asyncTest= (data, context) => {
  function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('resolved');
      }, 2000);
    });
  }

  async function asyncCall() {
    console.log('calling');
    var result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
    console.log(result); // expected output: 'resolved'
  }

  asyncCall();

};
```

---

Again, it's very strange that you are receiving Syntax Errors in this situations. If my suggestion don't work, try creating a new project (if that's a possibility) and test the examples there. If the issue is still there, my recommendation would be to use [Google's Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/) to create a [new issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) explaining what is happening with your Cloud Functions

---

**3. Why there's support for callback with the "promise chaining" being available? Are both method working?**

The [`publish` method](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/0.22.x/Publisher#publish) allows a callback function to be passed as a parameter. If you don't pass a callback function, the method automatically returns a promise, so yes, both ways of calling the method are working.

The other question is more a "callback vs. promises" question. This always an interesting topic, but a brief summary would be that promises and callbacks are not straight up interchangeable. Promises are much better than callbacks about what they do, but are not as well suited for general purpose as callback. [Here's a very good writeup](https://www.quora.com/What-are-situations-to-use-callbacks-instead-of-promises-in-Javascript-Should-one-use-promises-all-the-time-Which-will-lead-to-more-readable-code/answer/John-Johnson-140) about callbacks and promises.

Comment: Well, the issue is cleary between the keyboard and the chair ;) For the async, I was trying to put it before exports.asyncTest, so I guess it's not allowed.

async exports.helloPubSub = (event, callback)

Comment: The most common point of failure hahaha glad you found the issue @Thomas! By the way, if you want to get rid of the "on hold" thingy, I would remove the "reliable sources for project sample" question. It's probably what caused the question to get flagged

Comment: I also realized it's probably TypeScript not javascript, so a bit different from what I'm used to.